# Perform an action on Image Target depending on its name in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, game-development

I have created a scene which changes scenes to a vuforia scene where I can scan objects, from this scene I want to change to a different scene depending on the name[or through some sort of unique identification] of the scanned scene after an image target is found as I have more than one images which should display different information after getting scanned.

I implemented the code in a trackableEventHandler that overrides the default one, and added the code in the `OnTrackableStateChanged()`. I defined a `Transform` called `Transform` and I'm using this to get the name so I can change scenes with it. I followed an example and transform was used. Any different suggestion is fine.

```
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus){


        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED){

            Debug.Log("Image Found");

        }
        else{
            Debug.Log("Image lost!");
        }

        //
        StateManager stateManager = TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager();
        IEnumerable<TrackableBehaviour> trackableBehaviours = stateManager.GetActiveTrackableBehaviours();
        foreach (TrackableBehaviour trackableBehaviour in trackableBehaviours)
        {
            string scanName = trackableBehaviour.TrackableName;
              Transform.GetComponent<Text>().text = scanName;

            if(scanName == "scannedImage")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("ScannedImageScene");
            }
            else if(scanName == "otherImage")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherImageScene");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks good. What was the question?

Comment: the scene does not change at all unfortunately. I get the Image found message though.

Comment: Does your code ever get to "SceneManager.LoadScene("ScannedImageScene");"? Put a print in there and see what happens.

Comment: I will write the feedback

Comment: It never reaches that code, what could be the reason?

Comment: Well, either there are no "TrackableBehaviour trackableBehaviour in trackableBehaviours" for the for loop, or scanName != "scannedImage". Put prints everwhere to find out where things are going wrong